# Notepad++ Rexex to remove unknown multiple spaces between characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

Although I am not an expert, I can somehow remove known no of spaces between the characters like for e.g.

```
Something: INITIALIZATION OF
Something: PROPERTY PMISTATE
Something: 12 23
```

Find:

```
^(.*)([a-z0-9]+)\s([a-z0-9]+)
```

Replace:

```
\1\2 \3\n\1\2\3\n
```

Result:

```
Something: INITIALIZATION OF
Something: INITIALIZATIONOF

Something: PROPERTY PMISTATE
Something: PROPERTYPMISTATE

Something: 12 23
Something: 1223
```

But, I don't know how to do the same if the appearance or the no. of spaces are not known like for e.g
I would like to replace these words

```
Something: INITIALIZATION OF
Something: PROPERTY PMISTATE PMISTATE
Something: 12 23 23 .GET()
```

as following:

```
Something: INITIALIZATION OF
Something: INITIALIZATIONOF

Something: PROPERTY PMISTATE PMISTATE
Something: PROPERTYPMISTATEPMISTATE

Something: 12 23 .GET()
Something: 1223.GET()
```

Comment: You mean remove spaces on the line after `Something:`? Try `(?:\G(?!^)|^Something:\h*)\S*\K\h+` to remove with nothing.

Comment: You mean handle multiple words after the Something: ?

Comment: yes I mean to to handle multiple spaces after `Something:`

Comment: No, it seems you want to duplicate the lines first, right? Then perform replacement on the second occurrences.

Comment: Exactly, I would like to keep the original text and then add the processed text as a comment to process it further one by one

Comment: Ok, that cannot be a one-click operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to duplicate the lines first:

*Find What*: `^Something:.*$`
*Replace With*: `$&\r\n$&`

Click *Replace All*.

Then, use

*Find What*: `(?:\G(?!^)|^(Something:.*)\R(?=\1$)Something:\h*)\S*\K\h+`
*Replace With*: empty string (leave empty)

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(Something:.*)\R(?=\1$)Something:\h*)` - Match the end of the preceding successful match or a line that starts with `Something:` up to the line break, and the next line (with its starting word `Something:`) that is equal to the preceding line, and then 0+ horizontal whitespace symbols after it
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespaces

[image]

Comment: thanks can we also do it without replacing the line and simply by appending the text at the end for e.g `Something: INITIALIZATION OF INITIALIZATIONOF` where we have appended the text `INITIALIZATIONO` at the end

Comment: Do you mean the first step?  No idea, it is not necessary.

Comment: Well if I capitalize when duplicating the line, when replace with `$&\r\n\U$&\E` then Find What: `(?:\G(?!^)|^(Something:.*)\R(?=\1$)Something:\h*)\S*\K\h+` does not work, can you also suggest something for this, or simple how to delete the duplicate lines when my work is done!!

Comment: You may make the `\1` case insensitive by wrapping it with `(?i:\1)`

Comment: Well, my initial answer was right like that: no duplicate lines were created. *Find What*: `(?:\G(?!^)|^Something:\h*)\S*\K\h+` --> *Replace With*: empty string (leave empty).